# Which Model to use STA/MTA

Tags: windows, com

I'm trying to create COM component, where it will be frequently call by a excel application (excel will load the COM at its initialization) and another process (let say procA) also sends (with high frequency) windows messages to this component. Currently I implemented COM as a STA, however, I experienced that while COM is busy with processing messages from procA, the excel UI get stuck.

Please help me to get around this problem. Can I just create a simple window thread to process messages from procA while keeping COM as STA model ? Or do I need to make COM as MTA model, if so please explain how to handle it .

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Moving to an MTA requires you to perform all necessary locking to protect the state of your component. *And* it will add thread switch overhead because Excel's UI runs on a specific thread, which will block<sup>1</sup> while calling cross thread into your component. The other process is already incurring the cross process overhead so no real change there.

You could avoid the Excel cross-thread overhead by marking your component model as threading model 'Neutral'—it can still be used from any thread while not being tied to exist in the MTA (i.e. all in process calls will be direct, no thread swicthes). Write it as free threaded (all the locking is still needed) but just change the registration.

Given all the effort to ensure your component is thread safe you may find there is no advantage unless multiple calls into your component can really run concurrently. If you just take a lock for the duration of each method you are not saving anything over being in an STA. Finer grained locking might give an advantage, but you need more detailed analysis of what concurrency is possible, and then profiling to prove you have been able to achieve it. A look at [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_Law) will cover these issues.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is very simplistically put... the real situation is rather more complex.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, If I'm correct you'r telling me that I have to use MTA to fulfill my requirement and Neural model would be a better choice. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I'm not familiar with creating threads inside COM, Is it just windows thread that we use in c++ application ? Please explain or give me a reference.

My Plan is to create two threads T1, T2. T1 will process messages from procA and update a global object. And T2 will also access this Global object as Excel query to update values.So Global Object must be locked. Will this model be ok ?

Comment: @Nimo: Yes: if you were thinking about threading model of "Free", then "Neutral" is almost always a better option. Generally components do not create threads themselves (clients or COM runtime do). If you need a worker thread you need to ensure you manage it fully, not just initialising it for COM, but also all the typical problems of a library spinning up a thread (e.g. handling COM unloading your dll).